# how to implement code from ListView builder to Stickey group list when list item contains functions in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a listview builder with TransactionCard as a listview item,

here I have used long press and ontap function for showing action of delete and edit on appbar.

Now I want to implement my code to StickyGroupList so that transactions can be shown in group by date...but I don't know how to deal with function what is used for transaction card as it is based on index....so how to use index in Sticky Group list

here is my code

```
class ShowAllTransactionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShowAllTransactionScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<ShowAllTransactionScreen> createState() =>
      _ShowAllTransactionScreenState();
}

class _ShowAllTransactionScreenState extends State<ShowAllTransactionScreen> {
  bool islongpressed = false;
  int? selectedindex;
  TransactionModel? selectedtransaction;
  bool showit = true;

  final provider = Get.put(TransactionProvider());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:Text('Demo'),
        actions:[
          islongpressed?TextButton(onPressed: (){
            provider.delete_transaction(selectedtransaction!);
          },child: Text('Delete',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),):Text('')
        ]),
      body: showTransactions(),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        // backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        // elevation: 0,

        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return CreateSpend();
              }));
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }



  Widget showTransactions() {
    return GetBuilder<TransactionProvider>(
      builder: (_) {
        return provider.allTransactions.length > 0
            ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: provider.showRecentTransactions.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {

              final trans = provider.showRecentTransactions[index];
              return TransactionCard(
                ontap: (){
                  islongpressed = false;
                  selectedindex = null;
                  setState(() {
                  });
                },
                onlongpressed: () {
                  islongpressed = true;
                  selectedindex = index;
                  setState(() {
                    selectedtransaction = trans;
                  });
                },
                amount: trans.amount.toStringAsFixed(2),
                datetime: trans.date.toString(),
                paymentby: trans.paymentmode,
                category: trans.category.title,
                categoryicon: trans.category.iconurl,
                isexpense: trans.isexpense,
                isselected: selectedindex == index ? true : false,
              );
            })
            : Center(
            child: Text('No Data Found'),);
      },
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: Have you checked grouped listview?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/grouped_list this one?

Comment: is it not possible what I want with Sticky group list?

Comment: With the help of the grouped list you can make group

Comment: with help of date and use property with sticky or not

Comment: Like whatsappchat

Comment: can u implement my code with it....here I am confused how to use index of transaction card....

Comment: Can you please share me the expected output ?image

Comment: looks like u are not getting my point...its simple...listview builder providing index so that we can apply logic for selecting element....like ontap on long press.. but If I use Sticky group list...it does not providing index number of item...so how to deal with index....thats my point...it must be a easy way but I don't know how to manage...